# How to update the title of my next js app?

Tags: next.js

I have tried it using the  but it did not work I am using next js 14.
I tried using the Meta

```
 export const metadata: Metadata = {
 title: "Join the waitlist | Outquest",
 description: "This is Sign In Page for Startup Nextjs Template",
 };
```

But this did not work in tpe script and throwing errors.
also I am on the client side using "use client"

Answer (score -1):

Install Head Module:
If you haven't already, you can install the next/head module by running the following command in your Next.js project:

bash

npm install next/head

Or, if you are using Yarn:

bash

yarn add next/head

Comment: Why does this say "bash"? Did you copy this from somewhere?